# neo4j: What are the tradeoffs of --normalize-types=false?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

The `neo4j-admin` tool can import data from CSV.  [One of the options](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/4.4/tools/neo4j-admin/neo4j-admin-import/#import-tool-option-normalize-types) it takes is:

> `--normalize-types[=<true/false>]`
>
> Determines whether or not to normalize property types to Cypher types, e.g. `int` becomes `long` and `float` becomes `double`.
>
> Default: `true`

If I don't explicitly set `--normalize-types=false`, then the `neo4j-admin` tool produces messages like this:

```
Property type of 'foo' normalized from 'int' --> 'long' in /path/to/my-nodes.csv
```

My database has billions of properties, so I'd like to save space (and RAM) if possible. I know that the integer properties fit within 32 bits, and I don't need 64-bit precision for floating-point properties.  (See [this reference](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/4.4/java-embedded/property-values/) for the bit-width of each property type.)

#### What are the tradeoffs of normalizing the types vs. not normalizing?

For example, do narrower types actually save space/RAM?  Are they somehow incompatible with Cypher queries?

Answer (score 1):

I see that the [commit](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/commit/6ffe6e48e7f3bc49ace6c1855a05ccc8a9123600) that added support for normalizing types has this comment:

> **Importer normalizes property types to match Cypher**
>
> Effectively meaning that a type, specified in some .csv header that says that a
> certain property should be of type e.g. "short" will be imported as
> type "long". Basically all integer types will be imported and stored
> as long and floating point types will be imported and stored as
> double.
>
> This will be the default behaviour, but can be overridden for specific
> scenarios by providing "--normalize-types=false"

I presume this means that if you do not normalize types, then any un-normalized data types will have to be converted to/from normalized types whenever you use Cypher. So, even though you may save on storage space, your Cypher queries will be slowed down.

You may want to test it both ways to see if this is true (and let us know).